# Receive data from API and send it to another page via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, api, asana

I'm receiving data from an API (asana) when an event was made in my workspace via a POST method in a file called asanatarget.php

The data is correct and i can store it in file when received.
Looks like that:

```
    {"events":"resource":xxx,"user":xxx,"type":"story","action":"added","created_at":"2019-02-20T14:48:09.142Z","parent":xxx}]}
```

In the same file I send the data to a new file with AJAX with GET method:

asanatarget.php

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_HOOK_SECRET'])) {
        $h = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_HOOK_SECRET'];
        header('X-Hook-Secret:' . $h);
        exit;
    }
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php
 $input = file_get_contents('php://input');

    if ($input) {
        $entries = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
        file_put_contents('targetasanaDATA' . time() . '.txt', json_encode($entries));
?>
    <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/asanawebhook", // Working with laravel, the route is well defined
                data: <?php echo json_encode($entries); ?>,
                dataType: "json",

                success: function(response){ 
                    console.log("success " + response);
                },

                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {   // What to do if we fail
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                }

            });
        });  
    </script>


<?php 
} 

?>
</body>
</html>
```

When i'm directly loading asanatarget.php with test data, it's working fine and the data is passed to /asanawebhook but when the data is passed directly from the api, it's not working.
I checked and the data is always correct

Comment: You should use cURL POST if you want to send data with your requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP script generates only a HTML page (basically, a text).

The javascript can be interpreted and executed by a browser. But if no browser reads this page and execute it, nothing happens. PHP generates a webpage, nobody reads it, and things ends here.

You can use PHP too to send data via POST. You can build your query with  [http_build_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) and use `file_get_contents()`.